# Token is not being passed to client side with OAuth2 Google and Passport.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm building a small Node/React app where I'm trying to implement OAuth2 Google with a sign-in button.

My client-side is on port 3000 and server-side on port 5000.

From the client-side I have a link redirecting to the server-side auth page:

`<a href="http://localhost:5000/auth/google" class="button">`

Then on the server-side, I have some routes configured:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000?token=" + token);
    }
);
```

After signing in I'm correctly redirected to the client-side however I'm not seeing any token being passed in the URL.

Is there anything more I need to share from my code for debugging?

Update:

I have this error in the console:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http://XXX.X.X:3000/". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEXXXXXXXXXX+/TImW+5JXXXXXXXXXXXXXX='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Is this related? I don't think so as this seems to be mostly related to style and css.

Comment: What is the url of the client after the redirect?

Comment: http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/?token=" + token);
```

Comment: hum... doesn't change anything.

Comment: `function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        console.log("TOKEN>>>>", token);
        res.redirect("http://localhost:3000?token=" + token);
    }`
try logging it to see what content it has, if it is undefined we'll find out where the error is.

Comment: Already try that and test the token is being correctly print in the console log.

Comment: I found out a solution, you need to install a package `url`
and you can use it as :
`res.redirect(url.format({
       pathname:"http://localhost:3000/",
       query: {
          "token": token
        }
     }));`